# Python GTIN 8 Product calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code below:

```
while True:
    try:
        number = int (str("Enter"))
        if len(str(number)) != 7:
            print('Incorrect')
        if len(str(number)) == 7:
            print('Okay')
            multiplier = [3,1]
            times = ""
            total = 0
            for index, digit in enumerate(list(str(number))):
                total = total + int(digit)*multiplier[index%2]
                times = times+str(int(digit)*multiplier[index%2])+", "
            mof10 = total + (10 - total%10)
            checkdigit = mof10 - total
            final = str(number) + str(checkdigit)
            print (times[:-1])
            print(total)
            print(mof10)
            print(checkdigit)
            print(final)
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a number")
```

1. When I run the code the except ValueError is the only thing that prints, but it does not stop printing it.
2. I would like to know how to make this code accept 8 digit numbers, then validate if its a multiple of 10 or not, if it is it should be valid.

Comment: Try to keep your `try` clauses as short as possible.

Comment: Please explain in more detail how your program should act, and what input you're giving it. I know nothing of Python, but I can't see how you are getting your input, either. The first use of the 'str' function seems to convert the string "Enter" into a string object.

Answer (score 0):

Your program runs into an exception from the start.

```
    number = int(str("Enter"))
```

The program is creating an integer called 'number'. However, your code is saving the text "Enter" as a string, then converting it into an integer.

What you need to do is replace 'str' with 'input'. This means the program will print 'Enter', and save the user input as an integer. What you were doing before was saving the text 'Enter' as a string, then converting to an int, which caused the exception and made Python run the 'except' code.